# how to remove distinct node names in xslt 1.0 using contains and for each function?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <testInstanceResult>
     <device>
     <name>ritika-101</name>
       <side>D</side>
       </device>
      <device>
      <name>ritika-101</name>
      <side>E</side>
      </device>
      </testInstanceResult>
```

Here is xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:for-each select ="testInstanceResult/device">
             <xsl:if test ="contains(./name,'ritika-')">
              <xsl:value-of select="./name"></xsl:value-of>
              </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:template>
              </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output : ritika-101

I need name once i.e ritika-101 and writie into csv file.Let me know ,i checked in net but got confused.I am checking in my xsl for each device, if xpath contains ritika-101 den value of select but its coming two times(ritika-101ritika-101) just need ritika-101

Comment: Could you post any XSLT you have tried (even if it doesn't work), and the output you are expecting, please? If you are using XSLT 1.0, then you need to read up on a technique Muenchian Grouping (See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to remove distinct names, you want to remove duplicate values, and you don't want to do it using contains and for-each, you want to do it with whatever code is appropriate. A very badly worded question, therefore downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XSLT 1.0, you can make use of a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Essentially you will get the first element of each group, which will be your distinct values.

So, you are "grouping" the `device` elements by their `name` so you define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="names" match="device" use="name" />
```

Then to get the distinct values, your `for-each` should look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="testInstanceResult/device[generate-id() = generate-id(key('names', name)[1])]">
```

You could actually add the test on the text in the `for-each` too, although you may be better off using `starts-with` here.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:key name="names" match="device" use="name" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="testInstanceResult/device
                                [starts-with(name, 'ritika-')]
                                [generate-id() = generate-id(key('names', name)[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```